# Can't load images asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have asp.net project. In first load some pics don't load but after reload is ok! Pics paths load from json file.

```
`enter code here`<asp:Repeater ID="rptApps" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="white-box">
                                <div class="el-card-item">
                                    <div class="el-card-avatar el-overlay-1">
                                        <img src="<%#GlobalData.Images_Base_Url+Eval("image_name").ToString() %>" />
                                        <div class="el-overlay">
                                            <ul class="el-info">
                                                <%--<li class="inner_link"><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="<%#Eval("internal_url")+"?username="+Server.UrlEncode(Request.Cookies["CurrentUserUsername"].Value.ToString())+"&password="+Server.UrlEncode(Request.Cookies["CurrentUserPassword"].Value.ToString()) %>">دسترسی از داخل سازمان</a></li>
                                                <li class="outter_link"><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger" href="<%#Eval("external_url")+"?username="+Server.UrlEncode(Request.Cookies["CurrentUserUsername"].Value.ToString())+"&password="+Server.UrlEncode(Request.Cookies["CurrentUserPassword"].Value.ToString()) %>">دسترسی از خارج سازمان</a></li>--%>
                                                <li class="inner_link"><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-success" href="<%#Eval("internal_url") %>">دسترسی</a></li>
                                                <%--<li class="outter_link"><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-danger" href="<%#Eval("external_url") %>">دسترسی از خارج سازمان</a></li>--%>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="el-card-content">
                                        <h4 class="box-title"><%#Eval("app_name") %></h4>
                                        <h5><%#Eval("app_description") %></h5>
                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: check your browsers dev console (network tab)

Comment: Have you tried to clear the browser cache?

Comment: To @Siraf point, if clearing browser cache works, append a GUID or timestamp after the img src so browser forces refresh each time and can detect changes.. should look similar to <img src="my_image_file_name.jpg?v=20221004910"